# Tensorflow Model is not loading correctly

Tags: python, tensorflow, word2vec

I currently try to train a word2vec model for my company. 
For this I made use of the code on https://github.com/tensorflow/models, specifically https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/tutorials/embedding/word2vec.py.

I downloaded the german wikipedia dump and extracted the text information out of it. The task is to train a model with this data.

I work on a virtual Machine that has Ubuntu 16.04 and access to a Tesla M60. For the weekend I trained the model and saved the checkpoints in a seperate folder. At the end of the weekend the model was able to answer **36%** of the evaluation questions I gave to him (german questions similar to the example "questions-word.txt"). After training I want to load the model and run the evaluation task again.
For this I changed the code  in following lines (except for path changes): I added

```
    with tf.Graph().as_default(), tf.Session() as session:
       saver = tf.train.import_meta_graph(opts.save_path + "/model.ckpt-288720426.meta")
       saver.restore(session, tf.train.latest_checkpoint('./results'))
       print("Model restored.")
       with tf.device("/cpu:0"):
          model = Word2Vec(opts, session)
          model.read_analogies()  # Read analogy questions
       for _ in xrange(opts.epochs_to_train):
          #model.train()  # Process one epoch
          model.eval()  # Eval analogies.
```

I added the two lines for loading the model (saver = ...) and commented out the training line. Looking at the meta and latest checkpoint files and tensorboard shows a trained model, but when I run the code, the evaluation results in **0.1%** correct answers, which seems to me like the model restarts with an untrained model. I expected the result to be again **36%**.

Can somebody tell me the error I made in the code, or maybe even in my thinking?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are probably calling
`tf.global_variables_initializer().run()` in `build_graph` after you restored the model. So you basically load the weights and then overwrite them with the initialisation values and your network starts from scratch.

I implemented restoring the checkpoints with command line options for a small project working with Latin and you can have a look at the code here:
https://github.com/CarstenIsert/LatinLearner/blob/master/word2vec.py

Comment: Thank you for your help. Replacing the suggested line with the lines posted in the link actually solved the issue!

Answer (score 1):

Do you use preprocessing steps on your data during training ? Or do you use raw data as input of your network ? It is probable your model is correctly loaded but your testing data are not preprocessed in the same way as training steps.

Then it is better to create an empty model before calling restore ops. If you create an empty model before restore, Tensorflow will automatically load weights into your model.